# How can I publish my node.js server on tor?

Tags: node.js

On Windows,
my basic Node.js code:

```js
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get("/", (req,res)=> { res.send("hello")})
app.listen(443)
```

I ran code with:

> node index.js

I was Configured the `torrc` file from `C:/Tor Browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/`
I added `HiddenServiceDir info` and `HiddenServicePort 443 localhost:443`

and  `C:\Tor Browser\Browser\info` Folder automaticly Created.
I opened `hostname` from `info` folder.
in `hostname` file:

> nfqwdvxmmf6tboqbuvhss2txnhxlvhlm35iosnx6zmbmyaav7wfi3wid.onion

After, I launched `Tor Browser`.
I entered .onion link that in `hostname`.
browser gives this error code:

> SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG